# LNK2019: unresolved extrenal symbol when using std::ifstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, ifstream, lnk2019

I have a problem with using `std::ifstream` in c++. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Every time I want to initialize the `std::ifstream` object it gives me these errors:

file: **Shader.obj**

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned(unsigned int)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPAXI@Z)

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReport referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned(unsigned int)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPAXI@Z)

file: **msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)**

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol __imp___free_dbg referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl std::_Fac_node::operator delete(void *)" (??3_Fac_node@std@@SAXPAX@Z)

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol __imp___malloc_dbg referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl std::_Fac_node::operator new(unsigned int)" (??2_Fac_node@std@@SAPAXI@Z)

**Shader.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/vec3.hpp>
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

class Shader
{
private:
    /* some code */
public:
    /* some code */
    void setSourceFile(const std::string& filename);
}
```

**Shader.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Shader.h"

/* some code */

void Shader::setSourceFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream* shaderFile = new std::ifstream();
}
```

These errors remains even if i run just `std::ifstream shaderFile();` and even after passing arguments to the constructor. When I comment this, the program builds properly.

Comment: what if you write `#include <fstream>` only in `Shader.cpp`?

Comment: *"These errors remains even if i run just `std::ifstream shaderFile();`"* - Just fyi that's not even an object definition; it's a declaration of a function called `shaderFile` which takes no arguments and returns a by-value `std::ifstream`.

Comment: @StackDanny Nothing has changed.

Comment: This looks like you're linking a debug build against the non-debug (release) libraries.

Comment: It's not safe to mix debug and release.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm And how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure in debug mode all of the libraries you use are debug. Same goes for release. Your mistake is what you added in the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies setting

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, I just changed the build mode to release and it worked. So I will search for debug libraries instead and link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have linked some realease libraries(*glew32.lib* and *glfw32.lib*) mixed with debug libraries. So in **Project Properties->Linker->General** I have changed **Additional Library Directories** to the debug libraries and in **Linker->Input** changed the file names.

Thanks @drescherjm and @1201ProgramAlarm for advices!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0):

I've already split the Release directory and debug directory, but this error report still exists.
Include Path-same with the .h files.
Additional include path-same with the .hpp files.
additional library path-same with the path
input-different with the opencv_world452.lib and opencv_world452d.lib in release and debug modes seperately.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35046540)